# TypeORM NestJS (@nestjs/typeorm): Как не убивать приложение, если DB упала

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nest.js

У меня есть API на Nest.JS.

Есть /getInfo ручка, которая не зависит от DB
Есть /getInfoFromDb, которая зависит от DB

Я хочу, чтобы при падении DB, мое приложение не падало, а работало и я мог сам обрабатывать ошибку по ручке /getInfoFromDb

Что-то не вижу в connection options такого варианта

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: try/catch?_____